# Pgadmin environment for single user

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

if I want to connect to POSTGRESQL db with a Linux user that I've created, let's say "Joe", should I locate pgadmin folder within python environment under Joe's folder?

Comment: How and where was the db created?

Comment: @4mAstro With psql command `creatdb joe`, logged with user "joe" as this guide suggests: [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

Login using:

$ psql -U joe

List databases using:

```
joe=>\l
```

Connect to desired database using:

```
joe=>\c <database_name>
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what is this for. During the installation of Pgadmin a folder named 'pagdmin' has been created under `/home/myname/`, and inside there is the python environment. If I create another user, joe, so that I have  '/home/joe/` can he access to Pgadmin service regularly or does he need his private copy of Pgadmin folder and python environment? Maybe my question is stupid, but I'm new in Linux/Ubuntu.

Comment: This is how you connect to the database in the terminal. Pgadmin is different but I dont remember off the top of my head.